# Is there a shorter way for me to write this code?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm styling a table and I'm using various `first-child`, `nth-child` and `last-child` declarations such as the below:

```
.thankYouTable tbody tr td:first-child, 
.thankYouTable tbody tr td:nth-child(4),
.thankYouTable tbody tr td:nth-child(6),
.thankYouTable tbody tr td:nth-child(7),
.thankYouTable tbody tr td:nth-child(8) 
{
   border-right:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Is there a way for me to shorten this syntax? Its just out of curiosity really as I've had to do this quite a bit and it makes the stylesheet quite "messy". Whilst I can understand it, it may take others in future longer to decipher this. Is there a "best practice" for doing this kind of thing or is what I've done ok? (Realise this may be subjective so feel free to not answer this part).

For example would this not work:

```
.thankYouTable tbody tr td:first-child, 
.thankYouTable tbody tr td:nth-child(4),(6),(7),(8)
{
   border-right:1px solid #fff;
}
```

And I'm talking about pure CSS here, not using any kind of script.

Comment: With pure CSS, no, with SASS, LESS, yes

Comment: you could use a class?! (e.g. `.thankYouTable .specialTd {...}`) which you add to the appropriate tds.

Comment: What is the significance of the 4th, 6th, 7th and 8th child? If they're significant in your source HTML then you shouldn't be identifying them in CSS, but giving them classes in the HTML. Your rule seems awfully specific, which hampers maintainability.

Comment: Well, you don't need to specify `tbody` or `tr` as a `td` will always be a descendant of those. Other than than than, no - not with pure css.

Comment: @Dai, unfortunately, this is me working on replatforming something, so essentially me and and one other person have been tasked with essentially "copying and pasting" a site to another platform with minimal changes. We can only really neaten up CSS and make things look slightly better hence my question about trying to make it more readable. 

The significance is that they are part of a very long winded table that needs to be copied, unfortunate but that's my job!

Comment: Not without modifying the html to use classes directly on the sub elements referenced in the rule (which btw would perform better too).

Comment: @Mr.Alien, thanks, I've never played around with SCSS but I may well do in future, though as mentioned I can't really add anything to this project, which is a shame but will take note for future iterations.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware, thanks, might be easier to just set a rule and add it to the `<td>`'s! Thanks for all the other comments too.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can see you shorten it down is by using equation:
[..]
.thankYouTable tbody tr td:nth-child(4), //fourth element
.thankYouTable tbody tr td:nth-child(n+6) //every element after and including the 6th element
[..]